# Properly cast nested type to interface

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have an interface called `ITranslation` and two classes which implement it called `NameTranslation` and `DescriptionTranslation`:

```
interface ITranslation {
    string text { get; set; }
}

class NameTranslation: ITranslation {
  public string text { get; set; }
}

class DescriptionTranslation: ITranslation {
  public string text { get; set; }
}
```

I then want to be able to call a method with both of them.

```
public void DoStuff(ITranslation) { ... };
```

And the above works fine!

Say I re-implement my `DoStuff` method to take in a generic collection of my interfaces:

```
public void TryIt()
{
    ICollection<ITranslation> myList = new List<ITranslation>();
    DoStuff(myList);
}
public void DoStuff(ICollection<ITranslation> Param) { }
```

Works fine too!

But the moment I switch it to

```
ICollection<NameTranslation> myList = new List<NameTranslation>();
```

C# says that it is unable to cast it.

Why is this? How can I achieve it?

I want to go from `ICollection<NameTranslation>` to `ICollection<ITranslation>`

Comment: @Stefan I want to go from `ICollection<NameTranslation>` to `ICollection<ITranslation>`, sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @Stefan Nah, that's way too easy! Jokes aside, I need to actual types for EntityFramework to be able properly infer the relationships.

Comment: I believe `ICollection<T>` is invariant. Would `IEnumerable<ITranslation>` be acceptable for your `DoStuff` method's parameter?

Comment: @JonathonChase Well that worked. Didn't know abouyt invariant types, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe if you change your DoStuff method to:

```
 public void DoStuff<T>(ICollection<T> Param) where T : ITranslation { }
```

will fix your issue

Comment: While Jonathan's solution is my preferred one, this is the proper answer with respect to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be operating on the ITranslation like so:

```
ICollection<ITranslation> myList = new List<NameTranslation>();
```

If for some reason you need the Concrete Name Translation, and cannot have an ITranslation use the cast method

```
myList.Cast<ITranslation>.ToList()
```

Or just Operate using Generics

```
public void DoStuff<T>(ICollection<T> Param) 
    where T : ITranslation
```